# How to show full message text in org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage

Tags: java, apache-camel

> 2022-12-14 14:04:56,317 DEBUG
> [org.apa.cam.com.jms.EndpointMessageListener] (Camel (camel-1) thread
> #8 - JmsConsumer[my.queue]) activemq://queue:my.queue consumer received JMS message: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 13,
> responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:xxxx, originalDestination =
> null,..., content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@11ba49fe,
> ..., text = {    "foo": "bar",    "x...y": false}}

Notice that text is truncated. How can I see the full text?

`EndpointMessageListener` has this log line:

```java
LOG.debug("{} consumer received JMS message: {}", this.endpoint, message);
```

And for `message` of type `javax.jms.Message`, the toString() method implementation of `org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage` is:

```java
public String toString() {
    try {
        String text = this.text;
        if (text == null) {
            text = this.decodeContent(this.getContent());
        }

        if (text != null) {
            text = MarshallingSupport.truncate64(text);
            HashMap<String, Object> overrideFields = new HashMap();
            overrideFields.put("text", text);
            return super.toString(overrideFields);
        }
    } catch (JMSException var3) {
    }

    return super.toString();
}
```

where it always truncates to 60 chars.

```java
public static String truncate64(String text) {
    if (text.length() > 63) {
        String var10000 = text.substring(0, 45);
        text = var10000 + "..." + text.substring(text.length() - 12);
    }

    return text;
}
```

Can I find out what the complete message was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for instance test if the received JMSMessage is of type text, and if so, cast it and invoke the `getText()` method rather than the generic `toString()`:

```
if ( message instanceof javax.jms.TextMessage) {
  TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) message;
  LOG.debug("{} consumer received JMS message: {}", this.endpoint, tm.getText()); 
}
```

Beware it may also arrive as Bytes- or Stream-Message

Comment: Yes... I thought there were some configs to tweak to do this so that based on impl all can print message text.